# How to edit/modify or make changes on data for scheduled daily csv file upload to Data Studio?

Tags: database, csv, looker-studio

I have uploading data daily to google data studio, csv file but sometime upload data need to be corrected or updated or modified, so what could be a solution.
and also what to do when some data are missing/incomplete that day ,and only available next day?
for example :

case I :
 first day I upload csv file that contain

```
 date     type  value
    1/12     AA     3
    1/12     AB     4
    1/12     AC     5
    1/12     AD     8
```

and next day need to correct data for AD and AC another csv file for the same only two row

```
date     type  value
 1/12     AC     6
 1/12     AD     3
```

case II :
 first day I upload csv file that contain

```
    date     type  value
    1/12     AA     3
    1/12     AC     4
```

and next day another csv file for the same date

```
date     type  value
 1/12     AB     6
 1/12     AC     7
 1/12     AD     1
```

is that possible through Google Cloud Storage? csv file name for each day is remain same as the date.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a data management issue than a Data Studio issue. You need a separate workflow for maintaining and updating your data. Data Studio does not provide any functionality or interface for doing this.

You have multiple options:

1. Import your CSVs into a single Google Sheet and keep the most updated data in one worksheet. As new files come in, update that specific worksheet with the new data. Build your Data Studio dashboard from that worksheet directly.
2. Use a database service like CloudSQL. You can update your data table based on new entries.